# Add ssh public key to group instead of users on centos 6.5

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key, centos6.5, groups

I am a newbie to linux administration.

I have a box with centos 6.5 x64.

Ive been configuring ssh access via public/private key.

Ive been wondering if I could add the public key to a user group instead of a user (in the /home/username directory).

All users who can ssh will be under a specific group, which will have the public key.

If not, how should I proceed for new users created to have the public key automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want all users to have the same public key ?

Answer (score 2):

`sshd` normally reads authorized public keys from a file named `.ssh/authorized_keys` in each user's home directory. Each user would normally have their own copy of this file and would normally maintain it themselves.

The name of this authorized_keys file can be specified in the `sshd_config` file through the **AuthorizedKeysFile** directive. The default value of this directive is:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

You can use **Match group** to add another file to this list:

```
Match group special
    AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/special_key .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Match sections like this should go at the end of `sshd_config`. The match rule applies to all directives following the match until the next `match` or until the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to the `/etc/skel` directory which is used as a template for newly created users.

If you want this for only a specific set of users, create an additional `skel` dir and use this during user creation.